# Cannot read property length null error when used with regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, null

I'm a javascript beginner doing some CodeWars.com questions. I came across this question and I'm stuck due to a "cannot read property length null" error. I've tried to look up that error and can't find what the problem is in my program.

The assignment is:

"Check to see if a string has the same amount of 'x's and 'o's. The method must return a boolean and be case insensitive. The string can contains any char."

And this is what I've written so far:

```
function XO(str) {
    var x = "x";
    var o = "o";
    var numX = str.match(/x/gi).length;
    var numO = str.match(/o/gi).length;


    while(str.indexOf(x) > -1 || str.indexOf(o) > -1)  {
      if(numX == numO){
        return true;

      }
    }


     if (numX === -1 && numO === -1){
       return true;
    }

}

XO("xoxo");
```

The assignment also says that if there is neither an X or an O then the program should return true.

Comment: `match` could return `null` and `null.length` will throw that error. Try `(str.match(/x/gi) || '').length`

Comment: Why do you have a `while` loop? The value of the condition doesn't change inside the loop body. That should be `if`.

Answer (score 0):

This will not give you that error. When there are no matches, the match function returns null and you cannot get the length of null. A few extra lines solves this issue.

```js
function XO(str) {
    var x = "x";
    var o = "o";
    var numX = 0;
    var numO = 0;
    var xMatch = str.match(/x/gi);
    var oMatch = str.match(/o/gi);
 if (xMatch) {
     numX = xMatch.length;
    }
    if (oMatch) {
     numO = oMatch.length;
    }


    while(str.indexOf(x) > -1 || str.indexOf(o) > -1)  {
      if(numX == numO){
        return true;

      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }


     if (numX === -1 && numO === -1){
       return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }

}

console.log(XO("ddd"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making this problem more complex than it has to be.

All you need to do is make the string lowercase(to account for case insensitive), traverse the string, and when it finds an x, add 1 to a counter, and when you find and o, decrease 1 from the counter.
If it ends at 0, you return true, else you return false. There's no need for regexes

```
function XO(str){
  var count = 0;
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if(str[i] === 'x') count++;
    if(str[i] === 'o') count--;
  }
  return count === 0 ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to check the return value of `match` is not null before checking the length property. However

```
while(str.indexOf(x) > -1 || str.indexOf(o) > -1)  {
  if(numX == numO){
    return true;

  }
}
```

looks like an infinite loop if either string contains lower case 'x' or 'o' and there are a different number of each.

More simply:

```
function XO(str)
{  var matchX = str.match(/x/gi);
   var matchY = str.match(/o/gi);
   return (matchX && matchY) ? matchX.length == matchY.length : !matchX &&  !matchY;
}
```